# C# - Why do I need to upcast to Object before downcasting?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

In C# I'm in a scenario with the following types provided by the environment:

```
public interface IFoo {
}

public abstract class Base {
}

public class Derived : Base, IFoo {
}

public class Arbitrary {
    public Base GetBase() { }
}
```

Here's what I've written in addition to this. Note that I can guarantee in my code that `Arbitrary.GetBase()` will *always* return an instance of `Derived`.

```
public class Arbitrary2 : Arbitrary {
    public IFoo GetDerived() {
        return (IFoo)base.GetBase();
    }
}
```

However this code fails with the message "Cannot convert type 'Base' to 'IFoo'".

But if I do this then it works:

```
public class Arbitrary2 : Arbitrary {
    public IFoo GetDerived() {
        Object baseAsObject = base.GetBase();
        return (IFoo)baseAsObject ;
    }
}
```

Why is this upcast to Object necessary before I downcast it to IFoo? The two pieces of code are functionally identical, and the latter will reliably crash at runtime if the cast is invalid. I don't understand why the compiler complains.

Comment: `Base` does not derive from `IFoo`, you shouldn't cast to/from it.

Comment: Eric Lippert talks about a more specific example in his most recent blog:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/10/when-is-a-cast-not-a-cast.aspx

Comment: See section 6.2.4 of the [C# 4.0 language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) regarding explicit reference conversions.

Comment: What version of C# are you using?  This code compiles just fine for me without needing to convert to `object`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do this.  Your code should work, as is.  See this program for details:

```
using System;

public interface IFoo { }

public abstract class Base { }

public class Derived : Base, IFoo { }

public class Arbitrary {
    public Base GetBase() { return new Derived(); }
}

public class Arbitrary2 : Arbitrary {
    public IFoo GetDerived() {
        return (IFoo)base.GetBase();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Arbitrary2 test = new Arbitrary2();
        IFoo check = test.GetDerived();

        Console.WriteLine(check.GetType().Name);

        Console.WriteLine("Press key to exit:");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This wont fail at runtime.  The OP states that GetBase returns `Derived`, which does implement `IFoo`

Comment: The compiler, however, doesn't know that. The only thing it knows is that Base does not implement IFoo.

Comment: @ChrisShain The compiler can't tell - Note that I said it will "likely" fail at runtime - while it may succeed, the compiler will assume that it's an actual "Base" object since anything else would be a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle - any `Base` type should be valid there, which may or may not implement some arbitrary interface.

Comment: Right, I had written my comment before the edit.  With the edit, I agree of course.

Comment: Ah sorry mate, I must have missed it then!

Comment: So the type `System.Object` has magical behaviour such that the compiler does not perform type checking when doing downcasts from `System.Object`? Or is it because every type that implements `IFoo` (or any interface for that matter) will automatically be derived from `System.Object` (so the type-checking is actually still done, but .NET's inheritance means it will always pass)?

Comment: @David It's nothing magical - it's just that the compiler ignores the check for this if it's `System.Object` because it's going to assume you know what you're doing - When you're using Object directly, you're basically saying "I'm working with no type system here" and it'll allow the runtime checking to be the only check.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, right, but that's "magical behaviour" for `System.Object` because the compiler is treating it differently to other objects.

Comment: @David and Reed: I'm not sure the compiler treats `Object` in a special way. It just says _"`Object` is assignable from `IFoo`, so there's the relation I require, so the cast shall compile."_ But with `Base` and `IFoo` the compiler says: _"Neither of these two types is assignable from the other, so I must disallow the cast."_ Also see my new answer where I use a cast which I beleive is OK because `Base` is assignable from `Derived`. Not every `Base` is a `Derived`, though, so it could fail at runtime (David guarantees it won't).

Comment: And I don't think one should use the `as` keyword when you assume that the cast will always work. It's better to have it blow up immediately (should the assumption be wrong), than to go ahead with a `null` that will most certainly cause us problems (whose origin will be less obvious) at a later time.

Comment: After seeing Servy's comment _to the question_ (not to this answer), I think the compiler **does** allow the cast from `Base` to `IFoo` because `IFoo` is an interface, not a class (and because `Base` is not `sealed`). So the complete premise of the question might be wrong! Does anyone have a C# compiler?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Actually - it doesn't matter - The original question is flawed, and my (old) answer was wrong.  I edited to show fully working code, using just a simple cast.

Comment: Great. A minor detail: The Original Poster used `base.GetBase()`, and it's still in the above answer. And surely, it's not a problem for the compiler. But I think it's good practice to only use the `base` keyword when the member you want, is either hidden or overridden in the current class. That's not the case here, so `this.GetBase()` would be better in my opinion.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yeah - I would've removed it, but purposefully left it in to demonstrate that it is not the reason this is occurring for the OP...  I'd normally use `this.GetBase()` (to follow StyleCop guidelines)

Answer (score 1):

Your GetBase() method returns Base, which does not implement IFoo.

Comment: That doesn't need to prevent it from compiling.  It's possible (and indeed the case here) that the actual instance of the Base class is really a subclass that implements the interface.  As long as the Base isn't sealed this will even compile (or at least it does for me on C# 3.5; not sure what versions it does/doesn't work on).

Answer (score 1):

`Base` can't be converted to `IFoo` because `Base` doesn't have anything to do with `IFoo`:

```
public abstract class Base { }
```

Based on this declaration, there could very well be instances of `Base` which aren't of type `IFoo`.  Indeed, based on this declaration the compiler has absolutely no reason to assume that any given instance of `Base` would ever implement `IFoo`.

*`Derived`* implements `IFoo`:

```
public class Derived : Base, IFoo { }
```

But you're not returning a `Derived`, you're returning a `Base`.  By polymorphing it through `Object` you're effectively "tricking" the compiler.  You're telling it that you know more than it does and it should listen to you.  This can be fine, as long as you *do* in fact know more than the compiler does.  And what you know that the compiler doesn't know is that every instance of `Base` is going to be able to polymorph to `IFoo`.

In that case, why not just implement `IFoo` on `Base`?  That way you'd be sharing your knowledge with the compiler and everyone will be happy.

Comment: Good answer, though there is no "boxing" here, since the type being cast to object is not a value type.

Comment: @dlev: True, I didn't feel like it was the right term.  I just didn't think of a better one.  I'll change it to "polymorphing."

Answer (score 1):

The reason the compiler disallows the explicit cast is that `Base` doesn't implement `IFoo`.

If you can *guarantee* that `GetBase()` will always return a `Derived`, then you can just insert a cast to `Derived` prior to the `IFoo` cast:

```
public class Arbitrary2 : Arbitrary {
    public IFoo GetDerived() {
        return (IFoo)(Derived)base.GetBase();
    }
}
```

Of course this will throw at run-time if you're mistaken. Alternatively, you can use an `as` cast will just return `null` if it fails:

```
public class Arbitrary2 : Arbitrary {
    public IFoo GetDerived() {
        return base.GetBase() as IFoo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arbitrary.GetBase()` returns an instance of `Base`.  `Base`'s hierarchy does not contain `IFoo.`

At runtime, yes, your object is a `Derived` instance, but based on what the compiler knows--class relationships--there isn't a connection and therefore a way to cast from `Base` to `IFoo` as you are trying in your first method.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just write

```
public class Arbitrary2 : Arbitrary {
    public IFoo GetDerived() {
        return (Derived)this.GetBase();
    }
}
```

The compiler will see the connection between `Derived` and `Base`, so the explicit cast to `Derived` ought to be OK. Then any `Derived` is surely an `IFoo`, so there's no need to cast an additional time (that conversion is implicit).

Don't use the `base.` keyword. Either say `this.` (as above) or leave out.

EDIT: Also, your original code **did** compile, but my version might be a bit easier to read.